# Cannot use "image.save" on django

Tags: django, upload

My error is:

```
IOError at /mytest/photo/upload/

[Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'/mytest/photo/upload/2.png'
```

And my view is:

```
UPLOAD_URL = '/mytest/photo/upload/'

def upload(request):
    buf = request.FILES.get('photo', None)
    print buf
    if buf:
        #data = buf.read()
        #f = StringIO.StringIO(data)
        image = Image.open(buf)
        #image = image.convert('RGB')
        name = '%s%s' % (UPLOAD_URL, buf.name)
        image.save(file(name, 'wb'), 'PNG')
        return HttpResponse('ok')
    return HttpResponse('no')
```

And my urls.py is:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('mytest.views',
    url(r'^photo/upload/$','upload',name="")
)
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: What does your form template look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to specify the local path where you want to save the file. UPLOAD_URL is the path to your view, not the directory.

name a variable UPLOAD_PATH with full path for upload

then do something like :

```
UPLOAD_PATH = '/path/to/uploads/user'
if not os.path.isdir(UPLOAD_PATH):
    os.mkdir(UPLOAD_PATH)
file_path = os.path.join(UPLOAD_PATH, filename)
# security check
if os.path.abspath(file_path ).startswith(UPLOAD_PATH):
    image.save(file(file_path , 'wb'), 'PNG')
```